# Does kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers use GPS or Cell Tower?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gps

please tell me that if I use kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers instead of kCLLocationAccuracyBest.
Then will my iPhone use GPS or Cell tower?.

Answer (score 1):

It will use a mixture of the GPS Reciever built in, Cellular tower data and WiFi data to gather the best location estimate. There is no guarantee that it will use WiFi only nor is there a flag you can set so it only uses WiFi. If Cellular data is not available (for example in a remote location), it will fallback to WiFi and GPS Receiver.

Using `kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers` may have it rely on WiFi more often but there is no 100% certainty. It does however use less power so if it's sufficient to your needs then you'd be better off using that flag.